# EF7 alpha connection state problems

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use EF in a asp.net vNext SPA application.

I'm registering the context class with the build in dependency injection container using AddScoped() (just like they have it in the examples) but when I try to perform a delete operation on an entity I get weird errors.
Sometimes the delete works, sometimes I get a

```
Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
```

and sometimes I get a

```
The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.
```

This only happens for delete operations and I can't find a pattern on when the 'connection is open' and 'connection is closed' appear.

Here's my delete method body (the method is virtual because this is a base controller, though no overrides exist for it yet):

```
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    var t = await Items.SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.ID == id);
    if (t == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

    Items.Remove(t);
    AppContext.SaveChanges();

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: This could be related to [#141](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/141). If you don't think it is, would you mind filing a new bug so someone on the team can investigate?

Comment: Thanks. ([#555](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/555))

Answer (score 0):

Problem disappeared after migrating to alpha3